# Android create rectangle with four different colors

Tags: android, android-animation

[image: Colored Rectangle]
How do I create a colored Rectangle like above one. Is it possible to  control the length of each colored rectangle from java code? (above figure has a single rectangle with 4 colored inside it).  I've been searching for answers since a few hours & was unable to find a solution.

EDIT:
I'm using AppCompatActivity and here's content_main.xml & activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/parentis"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="#dc3838"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="#c4c11f"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="#2c64e7"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="#a11a7d"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Finally java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

     View child1= new View(this);
    View child2= new View(this);
    View child3= new View(this);
    View child4= new View(this);

    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentis);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam1.weight = 0.15f;
    child1.setLayoutParams(childParam1);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam2.weight = 0.15f;
    child2.setLayoutParams(childParam2);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam3.weight = 0.20f;
    child3.setLayoutParams(childParam3);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam4.weight = 0.50f;
    child4.setLayoutParams(childParam4);

    parent.setWeightSum(1f);
    parent.addView(child1);
    parent.addView(child2);
    parent.addView(child3);
    parent.addView(child4);
}
```

Comment: In linear layout create 4 view with different color... have look on my answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a **linear layout** with **android:weightsum="1"** .Then create 4 different views inside the linear layout with **android:weight=".25"**

Set your desired color for each views.

Do not forget to set the **orientation of linear layout as horizontal**

**Sample code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@color/your_color"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@color/your_color"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@color/your_color"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@color/your_color"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will distribute each color equally.If you not want to distribute each color equally then you can redistribute weight for each views.

To set the view length consisting each color:

**First create a blank linear layout in your xml file:**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/ll_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
  </LinearLayout>
```

**Then in the java file:**

```
 LinearLayout parent=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_parent)‌​;

    View child1= new View(this);
    View child2= new View(this);
    View child3= new View(this);
    View child4= new View(this);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam1.weight = 0.25f;
    child1.setLayoutParams(childParam1);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam2.weight = 0.25f;
    child2.setLayoutParams(childParam2);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam3.weight = 0.25f;
    child3.setLayoutParams(childParam3);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam4.weight = 0.25f;
    child4.setLayoutParams(childParam4);

    parent.setWeightSum(1f);
    parent.addView(child1);
    parent.addView(child2);
    parent.addView(child3);
    parent.addView(child4);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, what will be initial value for parent ? I tired something like " final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
                .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);" but unable to re-distribute the weights.

Comment: Create a blank linear layout in your xml file with horizontal orientation.then use parent=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.idyour_linear_layout_id);Then use the above code.

Comment: thanks for the update. I added them (see edit above on question) , still I'm unable to re-distribute the value from java code to something like .15f/.15f/.20f/.50f. Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set the color programmatically??

Comment: from your above code you have written: LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentis); ....but i couldnt find any Linear Layout called parentis in your xml file...you have to add that in your xml file....and also you didnt set the color of the view.

Comment: parentis is added in the first xml. (before 4 views) . I'll add color from java and test

Answer (score 1):

you can display colored rectangles on the screen by simply setting the backgroundcolor of imageviews:
`imageview.SetBackground(R.color.mycolor);`

Then you just need to put 4 of those `ImageViews` inside a `LinearLayout` and change their size programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

use this for same size rectangle .

rectangle.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#dc3838"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#c4c11f"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#2c64e7"/>


    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#a11a7d"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

and this different size rectangle....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#dc3838"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#c4c11f"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#2c64e7"/>


    <View
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#a11a7d"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

output like that .......

[image: o]

**Note:-set id to each one and change its size using LayoutPrams....**

Comment: This is not the way.Use layout weight instead

Comment: Yes, you fixed the width it doesn't support all device. Use weight

Comment: OP want to change its size pragmatically  than you have set value or you can use weight .

Answer (score 1):

first, you should get the screen size:

```
private Point getScreenSize(){

    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) YamsaferApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    Point size = new Point();

    display.getSize(size);

}
```

then write the following code:

```
int width = getScreenSize().x;

int redWidth = width / 4;

int orangeWidth = width / 4;

int greenWidth = width / 4; 

int cyanWidth = width / 4;

LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(getContext());

container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT,70);

container.setLayoutParams(params);

// create the red area:
View redView = new View(getContext());

redView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

redView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(redWidth,70));

container.addView(redView);

// create the orangeArea:

View orangeView = new View(getContext());

orangeView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

orangeView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(orangeWidth,70));

container.addView(orangeView);

//create the green area
View greenView = new View(getContext());

greenView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

greenView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(greenWidth,70));

container.addView(greenView);

create the cyan area:

View cyanView = new View(getContext());

cyanView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

cyanView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(cyanWidth,70));

cyanainer.addView(cyanView);
```

Comment: thanks for the response,do i need to add container to parent view or something so that It appears view?

Comment: yes sure, the container should be added to the parent view that will contain the view

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have a simpler layout with just one view and be able to change the sizes of the rectangles dynamically you can create a simple custom view. Override the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method and inside you can do something like this:

```
int rectWidth = getWidth() / 4;
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, rectWidth, getHeight(), redPaint);
canvas.drawRect(rectWidth, 0, 2 * rectWidth, getHeight(), orangePaint);
canvas.drawRect(2 * rectWidth, 0, 3 * rectWidth, getHeight(), greenPaint);
canvas.drawRect(3 * rectWidth, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), pinkPaint);
```

You can create paints like this:

```
redPaint = new Paint();
redPaint.setColor(*Your red color here*);
```

If you need the black border around the smaller rectangles you can just add some margin to the drawRect(...) calls above and add canvas.drawARGB(255,0,0,0) above them. For round rectangles you can use the drawRoundRect(...) methods.